# Add a line break after group of CSS pseudoclasses

Tags: css, html-lists, line-breaks, pseudo-class

How can I get a line break to be inserted after each group of two list elements? It doesn't necessarily need to be a HTML `<br />`, but just something to move the next two elements to the next line. Attemtping to entirely use CSS/3 here (over jQuery).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="headline_gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/picture1.png" alt="picture1" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture2.png" alt="picture2" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture3.png" alt="picture3" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/picture4.png" alt="picture4" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#headline_gallery li:nth-child(4n),#headline_gallery  li:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background:red;
    display:inline;
}

#headline_gallery li:nth-child(4n-2),#headline_gallery  li:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background:blue;
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use good old float and the n-th child selector

http://jsfiddle.net/QCcca/

```
li {
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Float the LIs left and then clear after every second:

```
#headline_gallery li {
    float: left;
}
#headline_gallery li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qjZYm/)